# PLS error on creating type as table of

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm creating types this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_type1 AS OBJECT
(
  -- fields
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_user AS OBJECT
(
  -- fields  
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_type2 AS TABLE OF t_type1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_superuser UNDER t_user
(
  -- fields
  field t_type2
);
```

The error arises on executing "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_type2 AS TABLE OF t_type1;" - it return syntax error. Therefore I can't complete the last statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construct `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE othertype ( field typetable )` is semantically incorrect.
You create your first type as follows :

```
SQL>  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typetable AS TABLE OF number; -- for example 
  2  /

Type created
```

And a second one as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE othertype as table of typetable;
  2  /

Type created
```

Or if you would like to create an object type:

```
SQL> create or replace type othertype as object
  2  (
  3    field typetable
  4  )
  5  /

Type created
```

Comment: as your answer didn't help I posted the full script. I have problem with any instruction with "as table of" in it

Comment: @deha According to your updated data in the question there should not be any errors. Provide complete specification of types along with the error(s). Try to execute it  in sql*plus in the appropriate order and show the result.